# Цикл зависает Backgroundworker

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть программа который создает сокет и начинает слушать определенный порт 127.0.0.1:9988
Проблема в том что программа работает но зависает. Пожалуйста помогите решить проблему.

```
Public void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
   this.Listen();
}
public void Listen()
 {    
     string data="";
     int i = 0;

     while(true)
     {
          handler = s.Accept();
          byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
          int bytesRec = handler.Receive(bytes);

          if (bytesRec == 0)
              break;

          data += Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, bytesRec);
          if (data.IndexOf("print=") > 1)
          {
              split = data.Split(new string[] { "print=" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
              string porttext;
              text = split[1].Split(new string[] { "=" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
              text[0] = text[0].Replace("%20", " ");
              porttext = text[0].Replace("&_", "");
              this.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(
                    () => { richTextBox1.Selection.Text += porttext + "\n"; }
                    ));
              port.Write("\r\0");
              port.Write(porttext);
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: Интересная логика возле `break` у вас. Да и сокет после кто закрывать будет? И в `data` данные каждый раз добавляются (`data += ...`). В общем, странно всё это

Answer (score 1):

В общем случае поможет такое решение:

```
  var autoEvent = new System.Threading.AutoResetEvent(false);

  var thread = new System.Threading.Thread(() =>
  {
     try
     {
         int bytesRec = handler.Receive(bytes);//Оператор который зависает

      }
      catch (Exception ex) {}

      autoEvent.Set();

   }).Start();

   if (!autoEvent.WaitOne(5000))//предел времени нормальной работы процесса
   {
       thread.Abort();
       return;//поток завис!!!
    }
```

Еще любители асинхронности могут усовершенствовать [пример из описания класса SocketAsyncEventArgs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.net.sockets.socketasynceventargs(v=vs.110).aspx), соответственно, подставив вместо

```
m_maxNumberAcceptedClients.WaitOne();
```

время

```
if (!m_maxNumberAcceptedClients.WaitOne(5000))//предел времени нормальной работы процесса
      //поток завис!!!
```